# neural network pattern recognition in matlab

Tags: matlab, pattern-recognition, neural-network

How do i go about to create and train a simple neural network in order to recognise patterns?
Does anybody have sample codes to guide me through or someone points to a direction?

Comment: Please show some effort. [Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&=&q=matlab%20neural%20network%20pattern%20recognition%20tutorial&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1).

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you could start by reading the Neural Network Toolbos [users guide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/nnet/nnet_ug.pdf). Also take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19997-neural-network-for-pattern-recognition-tutorial). You have code samples so it is a good start. Good luck.